# Memory error while reading lots of images

Tags: python, opencv, memory, garbage-collection

## Reading 10000 images using OpenCv python

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory)
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(directory,filename))

    #Different Image preprocessing function applied after reading it 
    #After 700 image preprocess it gives memory error
```

**How to resolve this error**

[image: image 1]

Comment: Based on the failed allocation, it looks like those are 3 channel images of size 4096x4096. That's 48 MiB of pixel data per image. You're trying to hold all of them in memory, since you insert them into a list. That means you need at least 48 MiB * 10000 = 468.75 GiB of RAM available. So, either go buy a LOT more RAM (and probably a motherboard that can hold it and CPU which can address it all)... or you will need to come up with a smarter algorithm that isn't so memory hungry.

Comment: Maybe he could make 1TB swap partition

Answer (score 0):

We overcome this problem by using the Global image read variable and empty the variable after getting certain information.